# redirect to 404 after capture image from jquery web cam

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs to capture image using my web cam. This is my html

```
<div class="row" id="webCam">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
       <div id="my_camera" style="width: 210px; height: 190px;"></div>
        <button id="takePhoto">Take Snapshot</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have use button to initialized web cam. That button calls to this function

```
//capture image frome web cam
function captureFromCam() {
  $('#webCam').show();

  Webcam.set({
    width: 200,
    height: 180,
    dest_width: 230,
    dest_height: 200,
    //image_format: 'jpeg',
    jpeg_quality: 90
     //force_flash: false
  });
  Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
  Webcam.setSWFLocation("~/jQuery-Plugin/webcam/webcam.swf");
}
```

I have use another function to Capture image.

```
function take_snapshot() {
  Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
    //document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
    $('#imgprvw').attr('src', data_uri);
    image = data_uri;
    $('#webCam').hide();
    Webcam.reset();
  });
}
```

My problem is thees functions are working and Capture image correctly. But after Capturing My page is Redirect to this error page

[image]

Comment: Seems it may be `Webcam.setSWFLocation("~/jQuery-Plugin/webcam/webcam.swf");` function, does the path exist?

Comment: yes, webcam.swf is in correct location, otherwise removing this part is not affected to code.

Comment: Seems that the issue is a redirect elsewhere, not in this code.

Comment: that problem doesn't happen by calling function inline. <button id="takePhoto"><a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a></button> but i want call that function using $('#takePhoto').click

Comment: i have found the solution by replacing <button> with <input type="button" id="takePhoto" value="Take Snapshot" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution by replacing  with

```
  `<input type="button" id="takePhoto" value="Take Snapshot" />`
```